# Align buttons on the same row

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get these buttons to align on the same row. I've added the buttons into a div and tried align-horizontal and display properties.

```
<div style="align-horizontal: center;">
<form action="#"><input style="background-color: #046738; padding: 15px 40px 15px 40px; border: none; color: white;" type="submit" value="INSTAGRAM" /></form>
<form action="#"><input style="background-color: #046738; padding: 15px 40px 15px 40px; border: none; color: white;" type="submit" value="TWITTER" /></form>
<form action="#"><input style="background-color: #046738; padding: 15px 40px 15px 40px; border: none; color: white;" type="submit" value="FACEBOOK" /></form>
<form action="#"><input style="background-color: #046738; padding: 15px 40px 15px 40px; border: none; color: white;" type="submit" value="DISCORD" /></form>
</div>
```

Comment: Why put each button in a separate <form>? And how do you intend to use those buttons? Each will do a GET or POST request? Or they can work with JavaScript, and not need forms at all?

Comment: The buttons will redirect to a URL

Comment: Use Anchor tags For example: `<a href="http://example.com">Example</a>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Align-horizontal: is not a valid CSS property.

You should do the following,

```
<div style="display:flex;align-items: center;">
<form action="#"><input style="background-color: #046738; padding: 15px 40px 15px 40px; border: none; color: white;" type="submit" value="INSTAGRAM" /></form>
<form action="#"><input style="background-color: #046738; padding: 15px 40px 15px 40px; border: none; color: white;" type="submit" value="TWITTER" /></form>
<form action="#"><input style="background-color: #046738; padding: 15px 40px 15px 40px; border: none; color: white;" type="submit" value="FACEBOOK" /></form>
<form action="#"><input style="background-color: #046738; padding: 15px 40px 15px 40px; border: none; color: white;" type="submit" value="DISCORD" /></form>
</div>
```

This will make your div a flex-box, which then allows child block elements such as the forms to be aligned center.

Comment: This was the correct styling that I needed thanks! I am having an issue now when I resize my window the buttons get cut off into the side. I added a div containing the buttons and styled with overflow auto but that's not it.

Answer (score 1):

I have refactored your code it's not a good practice to use so many forms just to navigate to another site for this Anchor tags are already present which are by nature are inline so you don't require any extra code check below.

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #046738;
  padding: 15px 40px 15px 40px;
  border: none;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div style="display:flex">
  <a href="#">INSTAGRAM</a>
  <a href="#">TWITTER</a>
  <a href="#">FACEBOOK</a>
  <a href="#">DISCORD</a>
</div>
```